# Vue transition do not work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here that my transition is not working. I am trying to make the switch to move to the right or left on click and it's working but no transition. I guess I am missing here something.

```
<template>
<div class="switchery" @click="activate" >
      <div class="switchery-check" v-bind:class="{active:isactive}"></div>
</div>
</template>

    <script>
      export default {
        data:function(){
          return{
            isactive:false
          }
        },
        methods:{
          activate:function (event) {
                 this.checked  = !this.checked;
                 this.isactive = this.checked;
          }
        }
      };

    </script>

    <style scoped>

    .switchery{
      width: 40px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      background-color: #09c;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
    }

    .switchery-check{
      transition: all 5s !important;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }

    .active.switchery-check {
      right: 0 !important;
      left: auto !important;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplementary to @acdcjunior's answer, I'd like to clarify what is actually happening in your demo:

You were actually close to a working solution (although not necessarily optimal). The problem is related to your usage of `left: auto` in your transition class (`.active.switchery-check`), which in this case [specifies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#Values) *the position of the element is based on the `right` property*. Since `right` has no initial value in the base class (`.switchery-check`), no transition occurs, and the element moves immediately to the right edge.

One solution is to change `left: auto` to `left: 20px` in your transition class, where `20px` is the width of the container element, specified in the base class:

```css
.switchery-check {
  left: 0;
}
.active.switchery-check {
  left: 20px;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      isactive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activate: function(event) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
      this.isactive = this.checked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.switchery {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #09c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.switchery-check {
  transition: all 200ms !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;              /* property to transition: left */
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.active.switchery-check {
  left: 20px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="switchery" @click="activate">
    <div class="switchery-check" v-bind:class="{active:isactive}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since `right` is computed from `left`, you could use the same solution above, swapping `right` for `left`:

```css
.switchery-check {
  right: 20px;
}
.active.switchery-check {
  right: 0;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      isactive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activate: function(event) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
      this.isactive = this.checked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.switchery {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #09c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.switchery-check {
  transition: all 200ms !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;              /* property to transition: right */
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.active.switchery-check {
  right: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="switchery" @click="activate">
    <div class="switchery-check" v-bind:class="{active:isactive}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>*Aside: When both `left` and `right` are defined, the position of the element is **overspecified**. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#Values)*</sup>

As @acdcjunior pointed out, an alternative to animating `left`/`right` is to use `transform: translateX(100%)`. This solution has a few advantages:

- **Better performance** The browser can [cheaply animate](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) with `transform: translateX()`. Animating with `left`/`right` causes layouts that could be relatively expensive and cause jank, depending on the number of these elements on the page. You can verify this in Chrome DevTools Performance panel: start a recording, click toggle switch to begin animation, stop recording, and examine the Event Log's Activity column. *(Tested in Chrome 66 on macOS High Sierra)*
- **More maintainable CSS** The container width only needs to be set once and only in the base class. That is, `.switchery-check` has `width: 20px`, and that's the only property that needs the setting. No need to make `left` or `right` match this setting. In fact, you don't even need to set `left` or `right` at all when using `transform: translateX(100%)`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      isactive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activate: function(event) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
      this.isactive = this.checked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.switchery {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #09c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.switchery-check {
  transition: all 200ms !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.active.switchery-check {
  transform: translateX(100%); /* NO NEED TO SET left OR right */
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="switchery" @click="activate">
    <div class="switchery-check" v-bind:class="{active:isactive}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- **More readable CSS** It's easier to identify at a glance the property being animated with `transform: translateX(100%)` in the transition class as opposed to getting the `left`/`right` settings correct in two different classes.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is `right` and `left` aren't triggering the animation, but your transition is well configured, see how `background: red;` transitions perfectly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      isactive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activate: function(event) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
      this.isactive = this.checked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.switchery {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #09c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.switchery-check {
  transition: all 5s !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.active.switchery-check {
  background: red; /* added for demo */
  right: 0 !important;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="switchery" @click="activate">
    <div class="switchery-check" v-bind:class="{active:isactive}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your case, one alternative would be `transform: translate(100%);` instead of `right` and `left`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      isactive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activate: function(event) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
      this.isactive = this.checked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.switchery {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #09c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.switchery-check {
  transition: all 5s !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.active.switchery-check {
  background: red; /* added for demo */
  transform: translate(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="switchery" @click="activate">
    <div class="switchery-check" v-bind:class="{active:isactive}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```